# Cordova iOS losing storage on app shut down

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Working on a cordova app for both iOS and android. Testing some new features, I noticed that my localStorage data was not keeping after i would stop the app via xcode, or close it in the multitasking view on the phone. Thinking it was because localStorage is not necessarily permanent, I switched to using PouchDB, which stores it via indexdb/websql. I'm having the same problem.

I am using the WKWebview plugin, so I don't know if that might be why. I've tested the usage of pouchdb in chrome on my laptop, and I've had zero issues with it.

**Edit**

Tested on android, same problem. Force quitting the app clears indexdb data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but I ended up working around the problem. Instead of saving to localstorage or websql, I instead just write a JSON file using the file plugin.

```
function getFileEntry() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // 1mb
    window.requestFileSystem(window.LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 1024 * 1024, (fs) => {
      fs.root.getFile('settings.json', { create: true, exclusive: false }, (fileEntry) => {
        resolve(fileEntry);
      }, (e) => {
        console.log(`error reading file ${fs.root.nativeURL}settings.json`);
        reject(e);
      });
    }, (e) => {
      console.log('error requesting persistent FS');
      reject(e);
    });
  });
}

export function fileApiAvailable() {
  return window.cordova && window.cordova.file;
}

export function readFile() {
  return getFileEntry().then((fileEntry) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fileEntry.file((file) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
          if (this.result) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(this.result));
          } else {
            resolve(null);
          }
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
      }, (e) => {
        console.log('issue reading the file');
        reject(e);
      });
    });
  });
}

export function saveSettingsToFile(settings) {
  if (!fileApiAvailable()) {
    return Promise.resolve();
  }

  return getFileEntry().then((fileEntry) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fileEntry.createWriter((fileWriter) => {
        fileWriter.onwriteend = () => {
          resolve();
        };
        fileWriter.onerror = (e) => {
          reject(e);
        };
        fileWriter.write(JSON.stringify(settings));
      });
    });
  });
}
```